# Python Inspect and Functions

Tags: python

I am trying to go through the json module and return just the functions. and then I would like to use inspect module to return inspect.formatargspec(*inspect.getfullargspec(func)) on each function from json.

This is what I was thinking, this obviously fails because `func` is a string.

```
import inspect
import json as m 

for func in dir(m):

    if inspect.isfunction(func):
        print(func)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) returns a list of attribute names of the object, not the attributes. You need to use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) to get the attribute.

```
import inspect

for func in dir(m):  # `func`: str
    if inspect.isfunction(getattr(m, func)):  # <----
        print(func)
```